# How to easy replace MessageDlg with Vista dialog, Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Delphi7 (cannot use latest). I want to replace (easy way, not making my form) `MessageDlg` calls with Vista style dialogs (must still work on old OS!). I need buttons Yes/No/YesToAll/NoToAll in this.
How to do it?

`MessageBox` isn't a way: I need all 4 buttons Yes/No/YesToAll/NoToAll in one form, or maybe checkbox instead of ToAll btns.

Comment: Do you mean Task Dialogs? Anyhow, isn't `MessageBox` better than `MessageDlg`?

Comment: `MessageBox` isn't a way, no buttons YesToAll/NoToAll, i need all 4 buttons in one dialog, maybe can use dialog with checkbox instead of ToAll btns. Yes task dialogs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Vista you use the native task dialog, `TaskDialogIndirect`. This has all the functionality you need. You'll need to translate the headers to Pascal, but if you don't fancy doing that yourself then you can use the JEDI header translations, for instance.

On XP and older there is no task dialog. There is no native system dialog with the functionality that you desire. Therefore you need to implement the dialog yourself. Create a Delphi `TForm` descendent. Add the necessary text, buttons, styling etc. Show it with `ShowModal`.

One of the issues with all this is that `TaskDialogIndirect` must be bound at runtime with `GetProcAddress`. In fact, use `GetProcAddress` to determine whether `TaskDialogIndirect` is available, and if not fall back to the XP code path.

If you don't want to build this yourself you can use one of the many extant libraries that offer such functionality. For instance: http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven

Comment: Any component exists, which can call Task dlg api, to show messagebox with 4 buttons yes/no/yestoall/notoall, or with checkbox instead of toall?

Comment: @RProgram you can call TaskDialogIndirect. It is not hard to do. But it doesn't exist on w2k/xp so you need a fallback there.

Comment: I don't think this question should be about particular library recommendations, such questions are off topic. What it should be about is the general approach to this problem.

Comment: You're right, and you gave me general recomm. And Synopse, which's Good.